# db4o won't save updates with javafx

Tags: properties, javafx, db4o

Preface: I frequent these boards but this is my first question. I appreciate the wealth of information on these boards. So thank you in advance for any help.

I have a JavaFX application and I am using db4o to back my data. The issue is the following:

Abiding by the JavaFX properties syntax we have a class like the following:

```
Person.java

class Person implements Activatable {
    private StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();

    ...

    public String getName() {
        return name.get();
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name.set(name);
    }

    public StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name;
    }

    ...
}
```

*db4o will properly store the data with the appropriate store() and subsequent commit() calls*. However, if I update any of the objects that have been stored, and then attempt to update them (via store) the updated data is not saved.

I have transparent persistence/activation working. I did the manual injection. I know it's working because if I do the following:

```
Person.java

class Person implements Activatable {
    private String name;

    ...

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return new SimpleStringProperty(name);
    }

    ...
}
```

Then everything is added, updated and saved correctly. The only reason I cannot use this approach is because Property Listeners (i.e., Change or Invalidation) do not work with this approach.

**With that said, is anybody aware of why db4o is unable to update JavaFX beans properties? Or am I missing something?**

Comment: Can you confirm you have `setName(...)` and `getName()` methods as well as `nameProperty()`?

Comment: Yes I do, I'll update to reflect.

Comment: OK, just thought I would ask the "is it plugged in" question... I haven't worked with db4o; I have worked with JavaFX Properties and JPA and [wrote up some of my experience](http://www.marshall.edu/genomicjava/2014/05/09/one-bean-to-bind-them-all/). See if that helps any.

Comment: Your write up on the 'Super-Lazy' implementation of the properties may solve my problem. I'll try it out and get back to you. Thanks James.

Comment: Would be interested to know if that works...

Comment: Hey James the code unfortunately caused object update errors for db4o (specifically, NPE). Thanks for your suggestions.